# Flex As3 Line Chart Grouping on Axis

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, linechart

[image]

I want to show these type of large scale data using flex line chart component on device,
 I have some filter like past week, past month and past 3 months

all have some/large amount of data

```
{ Date: "1/1/2015", Day:"Sunday" , DayAbv:"SUN", Severity: 2 }, 
{ Date: "1/2/2015", Day:"Monday" , DayAbv:"MON", Severity: 5},      
{ Date: "1/3/2015", Day:"Tuesday" , DayAbv:"TUE", Severity: 4},     
{ Date: "1/4/2015", Day:"Wednesday" , DayAbv:"WED", Severity: 7},   
{ Date: "1/5/2015", Day:"Thursday" , DayAbv:"THU", Severity: 5},
{ Date: "1/6/2015", Day:"Friday" , DayAbv:"FRI", Severity: 7},
{ Date: "1/7/2015", Day:"Saturday" , DayAbv:"SAT", Severity: 4}
```

Same as past month and past 3 months data in series

How can i group the Dates as per below image ? 
On y axis value would be same but on x axis dates should be in grouping.

In second line chart I have these type of data

```
{ Time: "08:10",  Average: 1 , Date : "1/1/2015" , Appearance : "Yes" },
{ Time: "09:25",  Average: 1 , Date : "1/1/2015" , Appearance : "Yes" },
{ Time: "11:20",  Average: 0 , Date : "1/2/2015" , Appearance : "No" },
{ Time: "13:20",  Average: 0 , Date : "1/3/2015" , Appearance : "No" },
{ Time: "15:55",  Average: 1 , Date : "1/3/2015" , Appearance : "Yes" },
{ Time: "18:05",  Average: 0 , Date : "1/5/2015" , Appearance : "No" },
{ Time: "20:30",  Average: 1 , Date : "1/5/2015" , Appearance : "Yes" }
```

In Detail, I want to show Week1 only on X axis and in week1 all the above point for Past week data, and for past month week1,week2,week3,week4 like so on. 
On one axis multiple plotting